# Invoke Method in Different Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class that subclasses `UITableViewController`. Based on user actions that are recognized in this class, I need to call a method on a table in the `UIViewController` were the table is instantiated. I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried to make the function static, but that won't work since there is an instance variable that I need to reach. I could probably use `NSNotificationCenter` but my intuition is that there is a better way. Can someone help? Thanks!

MonthsTableViewController.h

```
@interface MonthsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *monthsArray;
}
@end
```

MonthsTableViewController.m

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"calling the UIViewController");
    //this is where I am stuck!!!
}
```

SubscribeViewController.h

```
@interface SubscribeViewController : UIViewController <SIMChargeCardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    MonthsTableViewController *monthsController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *monthsTable;
}

- (void) snapMonthsToCenter;

@end
```

SubscribeViewController.m

```
- (void) snapMonthsToCenter {
    // snap the table selections to the center of the row
    NSLog(@"method called!");
    NSIndexPath *pathForMonthCenterCell = [monthsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(monthsTable.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(monthsTable.bounds))];
    [monthsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:pathForMonthCenterCell atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Send a notification or define a protocol and delegate in `MonthsTableViewController`. Then the `MonthsTableViewController` can tell its delegate that something happened. The `SubscriberViewController` can be the delegate. When the delegate method is called, the `SubscribeViewController` can call its own `snapMonthsToCenter` or anything else it needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in order to do this, you need a reference to your UIViewController from your UITableViewController. This will allow you to call the methods of this object. Typically you would call this property a `delegate`, because you're assigning the "parent" UIViewController as the delegate of the "child" UITableViewController.

Modify your UITableViewController (MonthsTableViewController.h) to add a delegate property like so:

```
@interface MonthsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *monthsArray;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@end
```

You will need to `@synthesize` the property in your `.m` file. You'll also want to import `SubscribeViewController.h` in your header here, if you haven't already.

Then, when you instantiate your `MonthsTableViewController`, set the delegate to your current object `MonthsTableViewController` like so:

```
MonthsTableViewController *example = [[MonthsTableViewController alloc] init.... // This is the line you should already have
[example setDelegate:self]; // Set this object's delegate property to the current object
```

Now you have access to the parent `SubscribeViewController` from your `MonthsTableViewController`. So how do you call functions? Easy! You can either hardcode the method call, or, to be super safe, use `respondsToSelector:`:

```
[(MonthsTableViewController*)[self delegate] snapMonthsToCenter];
```

In your case, the above code is absolutely fine, because you know that this method will always exist on this object. Typically, however, delegates are declared as protocols that may have optional methods. This means that although methods are declared in the @interface, they may not actually exist (be implemented) in the object. In this case, the following code would be used to make sure that the method can actually be called on the object:

```
if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(snapMonthsToCenter)]) {
    [[self delegate] snapMonthsToCenter];
}
```